# I only want to scroll one logo at a time in infinite carousel

Tags: jquery, html, css

I only want to scroll one logo at a time in infinite carousel. Below is my code. Any help would be appreciated. I tried defining singleWidth as 190px, which is the size of the logo. Although I'm still missing how to divide the negative space at the end to create the loop effect.

```
      <html>
      <head>
      <style type="text/css" media="screen">
      .infiniteCarousel {
      position: relative;
      width: 1354px;
      }

      .infiniteCarousel .carousel_wrapper {
      width: 1354px;
      overflow: auto;
      height: 162px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      top: 0;
      }

      .infiniteCarousel ._carousel_wrapper ul {
      width: 1252px; /* single item * n */
      list-style-image:none;
      list-style-position:outside;
      list-style-type:none;
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
      top: 0;
      }

      .infiniteCarousel ul li {
      display:block;
      float:left;
      padding: 10px;
      height: 162px;
      width: 190px;
      }

      .infiniteCarousel .arrow {
      display: block;
      height: 18px;
      width: 19px;
      background: url(hospitality_img/right_arrow.png) no-repeat 0 0;
      text-indent: -999px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 100px;
      cursor: pointer;
      outline: 0;
      right: 0;
      }

      .infiniteCarousel .forward {
      background-position: 0 0;
      right: 0;
      }

      .infiniteCarousel .back {
      display: block;
      height: 18px;
      width: 19px;
      background: url(hospitality_img/left_arrow.png) no-repeat 0 0;
      text-indent: -999px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 100px;
      cursor: pointer;
      outline: 0;
      left: 0;
      }
      </style>


      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
      (function () {
       $.fn.infiniteCarousel = function () {
       function repeat(str, n) {
        return new Array( n + 1 ).join(str);
        }

         return this.each(function () {
        // magic!
        var $wrapper = $('> div', this).css('overflow', 'hidden'),
            $slider = $wrapper.find('> ul').width(9999),
            $items = $slider.find('> li'),
            $single = $items.filter(':first')

            singleWidth = $single.outerWidth(),
            visible = Math.ceil($wrapper.innerWidth() / singleWidth),
            currentPage = 1,
            pages = Math.ceil($items.length / visible);

        /* TASKS */

        // 1. pad the pages with empty element if required
        if ($items.length % visible != 0) {
            // pad
        $slider.append(repeat('<li class="empty" />', visible - ($items.length %      visible)));
            $items = $slider.find('> li');
        }

        // 2. create the carousel padding on left and right (cloned)
        $items.filter(':first').before($items.slice(-visible).clone().addClass('cloned'));
        $items.filter(':last').after($items.slice(0, visible).clone().addClass('cloned'));
        $items = $slider.find('> li');

        // 3. reset scroll
        $wrapper.scrollLeft(singleWidth * visible);

        // 4. paging function
        function gotoPage(page) {
            var dir = page < currentPage ? -1 : 1,
                n = Math.abs(currentPage - page),
                left = singleWidth * dir * visible * n;

            $wrapper.filter(':not(:animated)').animate({//'margin-left':'-=190px'
                scrollLeft : '+=' + left
            }, 500, function () {
                // if page == last page - then reset position
                if (page > pages) {
                    $wrapper.scrollLeft(singleWidth * visible);
                    page = 1;
                } else if (page == 0) {
                    page = pages;
                    $wrapper.scrollLeft(singleWidth * visible * pages);
                }

                currentPage = page;
            });
        }

        // 5. insert the back and forward link
        $wrapper.after('<a href="infinite-carousel-loop.html#" class="arrow back"></a><a href="infinite-carousel-loop.html#" class="arrow forward"></a>');

        // 6. bind the back and forward links
        $('a.back', this).click(function () {
            gotoPage(currentPage - 1);
            return false;
        });

        $('a.forward', this).click(function () {
            gotoPage(currentPage + 1);
            return false;
        });

        $(this).bind('goto', function (event, page) {
            gotoPage(page);
        });

        // THIS IS NEW CODE FOR THE AUTOMATIC INFINITE CAROUSEL
        $(this).bind('next', function () {
            gotoPage(currentPage + 1);
        });
        });
        };
        })(jQuery);

        $(document).ready(function () {
        // THIS IS NEW CODE FOR THE AUTOMATIC INFINITE CAROUSEL
        var autoscrolling = true;

       $('.infiniteCarousel').infiniteCarousel().mouseover(function () {
       autoscrolling = false;
       }).mouseout(function () {
       autoscrolling = true;
       });

      setInterval(function () {
        if (autoscrolling) {
        $('.infiniteCarousel').trigger('next');
       }
       }, 2000);
       });
       </head>
       <body>

       <div class="infiniteCarousel">
       <div class="carousel_wrapper">
       <ul>
       <li><img src="hospitality_img/hyatt_union.png" alt="Hyatt Union Square New York" /></li>
       <li><img src="hospitality_img/the_ritz.png" alt="The Ritz-Carlton Dubai" /></li>
       <li><img src="hospitality_img/aman.png" alt="Aman Resorts" /></li>
       <li><img src="hospitality_img/caesars.png" alt="Caesars Entertainment" /></li>
       <li><img src="hospitality_img/lvmh.png" alt="LVMH Moet Hennessy Louis Vuitton" /></li>
       <li><img src="hospitality_img/palms.png" alt="Palms Las Vegas" /></li>
       </ul>        
       </div>
       </div>
       </body>
       </html>
```

Comment: How about some HTML and CSS so we can make a fiddle?

Comment: Hi Tim, I updated the HTML and CSS to the above statement. Sorry for the inconvenience. Let me know if you can come up with anything. Much help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've spent a few hours pouring over the code, and it seems that it is written to take all of the icons at the same time and run them across the screen. I tried to modify the code to just grab one icon, but it was a very ugly kludge. So I re-wrote the code in a way where you can put as many icons as you want in a div, change the times that it spends going across the screen and stop it at any time.

Here is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BExz3/10/).

It may not work for you, but it was fun and I learned a lot.

JS

```
var divwidth = $('.sliderdiv').width();
var firstmove = (divwidth * 0.5);
var firsttime = 600;
var lagtime = 1200;
var secondmove = (divwidth * 0.5)-50;
var secondtime = 600;
var numberimg = $('.holder img').length;
var n = 0;
animate( n );

$('#stopme').click(function(){
      $( '.sliderdiv img' ).stop(true);
});

function animate( n )
{
  var $moveimage = $('.holder img');
  $( $moveimage[n] ).clone().appendTo('.sliderdiv');
  var $slideimage = $('.sliderdiv img');  
  $( $slideimage ).animate(
                     { left: '+=' + firstmove }, firsttime,
             function() {
                         $( $slideimage ).animate(
                                            { left: '+=1' }, 
                                             lagtime,
             function() {
                         $( $slideimage ).animate(
                                            { left: '+=' + secondmove }, 
                                            secondtime,
             function()  {
                           $('.sliderdiv').html('');
                           n = n + 1;
                           if(n > numberimg - 1){ n = 0; }
                           animate( n );
                          }
                                             );}
                                             );}
                      );
}
```

Comment: I ended up switching out visible = Math.ceil($wrapper.innerWidth() / singleWidth) and $items.filter(':last').after($items.slice(0, visible).clone().addClass('cloned')); with visible = Math.ceil($items.innerWidth() / singleWidth) and $items.filter(':last').after($items.slice(visible-1).clone().addClass('cloned')); and it worked. Although I don't know if this is better or worse than your solution. I try your solution and see where I land. Thank you so much TimSPQR!

Comment: As long as it works for you, that's all that matters. You're welcome!